# How to convert PHP arrays？

Tags: php

This is an array of PHP database output：

```
[
  [hi]=>array(
        [text] => 'ok'
   )
  [work]=>array(
        [text] => 'usa'
   )
  [city]=>array(
        [text] => 'newyork'
   )
]
```

How do I convert it to look like this:

```
[
  [hi]=> 'ok'
  [work]=> 'usa'
  [city]=> 'newyork'
]
```

Comment: With a `foreach` loop, did you try it?

Comment: If you don't try, you won't fail, but you will never success neither. Try, fail, learn, success.

Comment: Alternatively even just [`array_map`](http://php.net/array_map) w/ [`array_pop`](http://php.net/array_pop) or alike.

Comment: how did you get the output above ?

Comment: something like `foreach ($yourArr as $key => $value) {
 $newArr[$key] = $value['text'];
}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just want to loop over the array and build your newly formatted array.

```
<?php

$arr = [
    'please' => [
        'text' => 'it'
    ],
    'use' => [
        'text' => 'will'
    ],
    'google' => [
        'text' => 'help'
    ]
];

$formattedArr = [];
foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
    $formattedArr[$k] = $v['text'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way using some array sorting methods to get us a one liner:

```
$formattedArr = array_combine( array_keys($arr), array_column($arr, 'text'));
```

`array_combine` is a php function that creates a new array using an array for keys and an array for values.

Simply enough, `array_keys` gets - you guessed it - the keys of the array. 
 `array_column` creates an array of a selected property from an inner array, so in this case, it goes plucks the 'text' values from the inner arrays.